# Windows Phone 7 - Hiccups on the start of an audio stream

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming

I'm using [ManagedMEdiaHelpers](https://github.com/loarabia/ManagedMediaHelpers) project as a base to a background audio streaming project.

The audio output is fine but sometimes is takes 1 to 6 seconds to start playing. During that time the device sends some strange noises similar to hiccups or scratching.

The mp3 I'm trying to stream have the following properies:

```
Bitrate: 320000
Sampling Rate: 44100
```

What are the possible causes to receive that kind of noises on the start of the stream when the rest of the mp3 plays just fine?

**More info**

I noticed that during the hiccups the fps count was below 20 so I tried to profile the application.

I got the following message during the hiccups period:

> Waring :Very high CPU usage by system threads: System and other applications
>   are using 65,02% of the CPU. This CPU usage may be caused by other
>   tasks that are running on the system or they may be caused by system
>   operations that are triggered by a user application. Ensure that no
>   other tasks are running on the system during profiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an hardware limitation of HTC Radar.

I Just tried the same code on an Samsung OMNIA 7 and the stream is just perfect. Also there's no penalty on the fps count so I think that on this device there's no CPU hogging.

Strangely [gsmarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=3537&idPhone2=4131) says that both devices have the same CPU.